# Netbeans, Goworks Golang IDE, Not found4, Not found9, Not found12

Tags: command-line, scripts, configuration, netbeans

I wanted to try the Goworks (IDE for golang).

When I launch the application

```
$ cd goworks/bin
$ ./goworks
```

it gives the following error.

```or-tag-here
: not found4: ./../etc/goworks.conf:
: not found9: ./../etc/goworks.conf:
: not found12: ./../etc/goworks.conf:
...
```

The config file exists and when I run the `cat ./../etc/goworks.conf` command it yields the content of the config file. It is a bit strange to me.

When I open the shell script in a text editor `subl goworks`

```or-tag-here
#!/bin/sh

#
# resolve symlinks
#

PRG=$0

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '^.*-> \(.*\)$' 2>/dev/null`
    if expr "$link" : '^/' 2> /dev/null >/dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
    else
    PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
    fi
done

progdir=`dirname "$PRG"`
APPNAME=`basename "$PRG"`

if [ -f "$progdir/../etc/$APPNAME".conf ] ; then
    . "$progdir/../etc/$APPNAME".conf # Here is the problem
fi
...
```

The problem starts from inside the `if` condition.

I do not even know from where to start due to my limited knowledge on POSIX command line apps.

Comment: I can't help I'm afraid, but you probably should report it as a bug [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/goworks/issues). Say what version of Ubuntu you're running etc

Comment: @Ads20000 thank you. I will do that as well.

Comment: How did you obtain / install it? my *guess* would be that there is an issue with the line-endings of the `goworks.conf` file - look at the output of `cat -net ./../etc/goworks.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @steeldriver. It is solved. I just extracted the `zip` archive and directly run. Like you mentioned the goworks.conf file had an extra junk character at the end of each line.

I was suspecting it with a '\r' character but the Sublime Text Editor can not find this character even in a Regex mode.

Below is the output of

`$ cat -net ./../etc/goworks.conf`

```
 1  # ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform^M$
 2  default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/dev"^M$
 3  default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/dev"^M$
 4  ^M$
 5  # options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit^M$
 6  # command line switches^M$
 7  default_options="--branding goworks -J-server -J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-Xms384m -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true"^M$
 8  # for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea^M$
 9  ^M$
10  # default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch^M$
11  #jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"^M$
12  ^M$
13  # clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)^M$
14  #extra_clusters=^M$
```

This issue is resolved now.

The program throws another issue while it is loading, however, it is going to be a different question.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes `^M` is indeed a representation of the carriage return character - you should be able to remove with the `dos2unix` utility, or with various other methods such as `:set ff=unix` in `vi`, or `sed 's/\r$//'`